# Suggested edits on meta - something weird

Tags: support, bug, suggested-edits, meta

Normally, on a per-site meta, the suggested edit button is grayed out with a message that says that suggested edits are not permitted on meta sites:

[image]

However, when manually typing the URL to suggest an edit, the message does not match:

[image]

As you can see, the messages are different. The one on the manual edit URL should be changed to be the same as on the tooltip.

Comment: Is there *any* way to reach the wrong message except typing it in manually?

Comment: Maybe a userscript adds a link in, or an API-based app looks at it and displays it in the app upon triggering a programmatic access?

Comment: @DanielBeck does that make a difference? This is minor, obviously, but a bug nevertheless since it is an inconsistency.

Comment: Probably status-wontfix on this, as you have to manually play with the URL in order to trigger it, but passed it along.