# Typo in reputation recalc error message

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, rep-recalc

Now that the reputation recalc feature has been removed, the "Trigger Reputation Recalc" button is gone from https://superuser.com/reputation, and attempts to use the original URL to get a recalc (https://superuser.com/reputation?recalc=true) results in the following error message:

> Reputation recalc can no longer be triggered. If your rep is off after a post deletion, allow 5 minutes for it to sync up. If your reputation is off for another reason: let us know on meta.stackoverflow.com.
>
> We have disabled this ability because reputation should be in sync without any user intervention. If it's not in sync for more than 5 minutes, it's a bug. We need to **investgate** that bug and a recalc hinders fixing the actual cause.

As you can see, "investgate" should be "invest***i***gate". When will this typo be fixed?

Comment: You heard of [Watergate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watergate_scandal‎), right? This is the Investgate scandal. Don't bring light to it.

Comment: @CanadianLuke Oh, come on. I didn't know that there was some subjective reason that they purposely left this typo in.

Comment: I meant that as a joke, I hope you realize :)

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a genuine issue that should be fixed.

Comment: This isn't an April Fool's prank here. It's still March 31 where I live, and you should click on the link to see the typo.

Comment: I suspect the downvote was due to someone thinking that such a trivial issue shouldn't occupy the developers' time. This is a tiny, barely noticeable typo on a page that only a handful of people will ever see. There are *so* much bigger fish to fry. If that was the downvoter's reasoning, I tend to agree, but I won't pummel you with another downvote, because I'm nice.

Comment: @allquixotic http://meta.superuser.com/questions/7741/suggested-edits-on-meta-something-weird#comment19817_7741

Comment: @allquixotic The great thing about trivial issues is that they're super easy and trivial to fix. We'd rather folks reported problems (even if we aren't going to address them) than decided they weren't important enough and never let us know.

Comment: The problem is now fixed, making this question obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will be fixed in the next deploy. Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind closing my question as the problem is fixed now?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi No need. We don't generally close bug reports once they're fixed. We just mark them [status-completed].

Comment: Well, I asked just because I noticed many old bug reports that are fixed being closed as too localized. Also, would you mind fixing this other trivial issue, please? http://meta.superuser.com/questions/7741/suggested-edits-on-meta-something-weird